# how to delete entry in content database while delete list item

Tags: sharepoint

When I delete a list item from a web site based on MOSS 2007, the content database will set its DeleteTransactionId instead of deleting it. That's a waste of space for me because I won't use thes item anymore.

Is there any way to delete a list item from the list and the content database in the same time?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Are you really THAT worried about the 'space'?

2) Does emptying the recycle bin remove those entries?

3) Keep in mind MS recommends you DO NOT do anything against the database.

4) See http://rdacollab.blogspot.com/2008/08/mosssharepoint-2007-deleting-deleted.html for some SQL to do the job (but read the Disclaimer first).

Answer (score 1):

The item has been moved to Recycle Bin.  Once item is removed from Recycle Bin it will be deleted from database.  If you really want it removed right away then

A) You can disable Recycle Bin (keep in mind there are 2 Recycle Bins).

B) If you are using the API then you can just do SPListItem.Delete.